# Remove all characters except for certain string in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm trying to remove all characters except for a list of specific strings that I have specified from a column in R.

My data:

```
oldlist <- c("ljwefhwordlsfk", "kjrghewletterweifj", "esjnumbersf", "ggkjherletter", "slrgjwordoggr")
```

My expected outcome:

```
desiredlist <- c("word", "letter", "number", "letter", "word")
```

What I have tried but won't work:

```
helpvector <- c("word", "letter", "number")

neuenummer <- gsub(paste0("[^", paste(helpvector, collapse=""), "]+"), "", oldlist)
```

Comment: What is your expected output.  If it is the 'desiredlist', thhen the second element of 'oldlist' doesn't have 'list'

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit, the expected output is desiredlist

Comment: If  you check the  second element of 'oldlist', there is no 'list'

Comment: Now the example should be right. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: What is your rationale for `helpvector`? I'm a little confused by that part.

Comment: If it is to remove the letters for correpsonding elements, the length is mismatching.  oldlist should have  the same length as helpvector i.e. `str_replace_all(oldlist, paste0("[", helpvector, "]"), "")`

Comment: @HaydenY. sorry, I really rushed over creating this example and forgot to take out the original values, now I have created an example that matches what I'm trying to achieve, which is create a vector that contains 3 words, and delete all characters that do not match the exact strings specified in that vector from my column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(oldlist, str_c(helpvector, collapse="|"), simplify = TRUE)[,1]
#[1] "word"   "letter" "number" "letter" "word"
```

---

Or with `gregexpr/regmatches` from `base R`

```
unlist(regmatches(oldlist, gregexpr(paste0(helpvector, collapse="|"), oldlist)))
#[1] "word"   "letter" "number" "letter" "word"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
stri_extract_all_regex(oldlist, '(word|letter|number)') %>% unlist()
[1] "word"   "letter" "number" "letter" "word"
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is also really nice.

Comment: Not at all. Get familiar with the `stringi` package. Has amazing help docs.